# Files for GNOME 42.6, a.k.a. Nautilus, (Ubuntu 22.04.3) indexes external SSD very slowly

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, filemanager

I have an external SSD formatted as exfat. Files for GNOME (Nautilus) takes indefinite time (1 second to 200 seconds in my tests) to show the content of directories.

- Files for GNOME is version 42.6
- Ubuntu is version 22.04.3

Is there a fix?

**Edit**

It is also very slow at opening plain text files and saving to them.

Same on Ubuntu 23.04 and Files for GNOME 44.0.

May this be something related to the exfat filesystem?

Thanks,
Luca